# How to exclude visitors whose name contains forbidden words?

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

Prompt a bot for a group of telegrams that would exclude visitors whose name contains the word "sex" and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at this site. I think your question gets an answer [here](https://sendpulse.com/knowledge-base/chatbot/create-telegram-chatbot)!!!

Comment: Can you please recheck the given link as it says "404: page not found".

Comment: https://sendpulse.com/knowledge-base/chatbot/create-telegram-chatbot.
Try this.

Answer (score 0):

Please specify the language you are using to code the bot.

You can block messages that contains prohibited word. (JAVA Code) -

```
@Override
public void onUpdateRecieved(Update update){
    if(update.getMessage().getText() == "<prohibited word>"){
        DeleteMessage deleteMessage = new DeleteMessage();
        deleteMessage.setChatId(update.getMessage().getChatId().toString());
        deleteMessage.setMessageId(update.getMessage().getMessageId());
        try {
            execute(deleteMessage);
        } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Also I will suggest you to read Telegram Bot API [Documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api).